# Unit testing IQueryable.Max on RowVersion property

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, iqueryable

I have the following model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    ...

    public byte[] RowVersion []

    ...
}
```

I need to build a query (IQueryable) which, beyond other things, filter the RowVersion property, order it and also calculate the Max on it.

No problem at all, because everything works using a real connection to the DB. The problem I have is when I mock the context to unit test the class that build the query.

Here's the how I mock the context:

```
Mock<MyContext> mock = new Mock<MyContext>();
mock.Setup(x => x.MyModels).Returns(MockList(myModelsCollection));
```

When I run my unit tests I get the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException : At least one object must implement IComparable.

Any hint to solve this problem?

Note: the dataset it's pretty big so I need to use IQueryable instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: Why would you want to order/max a rowversion column? That makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidG `rowversion` is documented as "Incrementing" the value each update to the row, so if you had multiple versions of the same row the one with the "max" rowversion would be the current version of the row.

Comment: @DavidG the maximum value of the rowversion column identifies the latest inserted or updated row.

Comment: @dario The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand and reproduce your problem.